# Failing Jenkins build when Checkmarx job fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, checkmarx

I have configured a Checkmarx job in Jenkins and I wanted to integrate the Job with the actual build job of a repository.
In my Jenkinsfile I've configured this as a stage and the job gets executed.

The question is how to I listen to failures on the Checkmarx job and accordingly change the status of my build job? Here's a snippet from my JenkinsFile

```
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building'
                     ...
                     ........
                     ...........
            }
        }

        stage('Checkmarx') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Kicking off checkmarx job..'
                build job: 'checkmarx', wait: false
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would just make it wait for the downstream job it would fail with it

```
steps {
    echo 'Kicking off checkmarx job..'
    build job: 'checkmarx', wait: true
}
```

Comment: Checkmarx takes a long time to complete, hence wanted to run it in parallel.

Comment: So your main job is ending with success and from downstream you want to retrospectively change this result?